# Codeigniter + Mysql = accents not being saved properly

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, diacritics

I have a database that I run using MySql and codeigniter that has a mix of english and french names in it.

The french names, like Andrée, come back as AndrÃ©e, and other various obviously incorrect.

How do I prevent this from happening, and that we can put in Andrée and get Andrée back?

Thanks!

Comment: have you set your mysql database to UTF-8/Unicode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Table collation Utf8_unicode_ci, row collation is UTF8_Unicode_CI, codeigniter database settings, set to Utf8_unicode_ci

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out, I had to tell php that utf-8 was the default in the config file. All is well since then!

Answer (score 0):

If your database settings are set to UTF-8 (and by the sound of your comments they are), you may be seeing these strange characters because your page is not rendering as UTF-8.

UTF-8 documents are supposed to come with a Content-Type header to say what encoding they should be parsed as. To add this header you can add the following code either before or after your view/s get loaded:

```
$this->output->set_content_type('text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

In your document's  you should add the following line:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

If you are rendering text only then you will want to change the part of the header where it says `text/html` to something more appropriate such as `text/plain`.

Comment: I looked at the database value in Phpmyadmin, it has the proper accent and spelling, so it's now Codeigniter side problems.

This has been in my header for all my views "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> "

Nothing changes when I put "$this->output->set_content_type('text/html; charset=utf-8');" in the controller right before I load the view.

Comment: It should logically be working, but without seeing the full setup I would recommend simply using the function `htmlentities()` (http://php.net/htmlentities) for displaying the UTF-8 names. The code delivered to the browser should then be showing `Andr&eacute;e` instead of `Andrée`.